# How can I stop myself from picking up certain items for a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I go to pokestops and spin the coin it picks up all items if I press them or not. Is there a way to leave items and not pick them up? For instance I want to pick up pokeballs, but leave the revives.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to avoid picking up certain items. However, you can delete items from your inventory. When you are viewing items, tap on the trash bin for the item that you'd like to reduce the quantity of. You'll then see a pop-up asking how many items you'd like to discard. Select the appropriate amount you'd like to get rid of and tap yes.

[image: Deleting items from Pokemon Go]

Answer (score 3):

There is not, you will collect the items whether or not you tap on them. However you can simply trash them in the items menu. It will ask you how many you want to trash and that will free up your inventory!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot select only what you want to receive from Pokéstops, you will always collect everything that you get from one. You can, however, trash any items you do not want by going to your items and click on the trash icon. You can delete multiple of an item at a time.